# Add AJAX string data to hidden field

Tags: jquery, ajax

My ajax code is as follows:

```
var customername = $('#SelectCustomer').val();
var customercode;

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "OrderFormServices.asmx/GetCustomerCode",
    data: { 'customername': customername},
    dataType: "json",
    cache: false,
    success: function (data) {
        customercode = data;
        $('#hiddenCustomerCode').value = customercode;
    }
});
```

This returns data like so

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<string xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">CUST-009012</string>
```

How can I assign this value to `customercode` ??

I've tried `customercode = (data.d);` but this still doesn't work

Comment: `$('#hiddenCustomerCode').val(customercode)` use `.val()` show what is the response from the ajax..

Comment: Also.. shouldn't the `dataType:"json"` be `dataType:"xml"` ? You're getting XML data back from the server...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're using jQuery, wrap the `xml`-response inside a jQuery object and call `find` on it to get the corresponding node:

```
$.ajax({ 
    type: "POST",
    url: "OrderFormServices.asmx/GetCustomerCode",
    data: { 'customername': customername},
    dataType: "xml",
    cache: false,
    success: function (data) {            
         $customercode= $(data).find("string");
         $('#hiddenCustomerCode').val($customercode);
    }
});
```

Comment: `dataType: "xml",` is set do you need to `$.parseXML(data)`?